# Remove Infinity values in List<double> C#

Tags: c#

I have List with name `listDouble`, any item have valued is Infitity.

I want to remove it from `listDouble`.

Tried with:

`listDouble.RemoveAll(item => item.Equals(0.0) && item.Equals("Infinity"));`

I also check before add `result` to List<> with code:

```
double result;
if (result == Double.NegativeInfinity)
    result = 0;
else
    return result;
```

But can't remove values = Infinity in `List<Double> listDouble`.

Comment: Can you also add case check, i.e. if `Infinity` is is lowercase, then you need to use lowercased value.

Comment: Why comparing string *item.ToString() == "Infinity"*? Isn't `item` of type `double`?

Comment: why are you comparing it to `0.0` first? It would almost work if you remove this condition

Comment: I also want to remove `item = 0.0`.

Comment: If you want to perform action `X` on condition `A` *AND ALSO* perform `X` on condition `B`, then you want to perform `X` on condition `A OR B`, not on condition `A AND B`

Comment: I want to perform action `X` with condition `A` **AND ALSO** perform `X` with condition `B`.

Comment: But you want to remove the item when it's 0.0 OR is infinity and not when it's 0.0 AND is infinity because it will never happen

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is a more elegant solution, just use `double.IsInfinity()`

```
List<double> doubleTest = new List<double>()
{
    0,
    12233302.4,
    double.NegativeInfinity,
    double.PositiveInfinity,
    5
};

doubleTest.RemoveAll(item => double.IsInfinity(item) || item == 0);
```

Updated after comment stating he also wants to remove the value `0`.

Comment: Or simply `doubleTest.RemoveAll(double.IsInfinity)`.

Answer (score 2):

To remove infinite values:

```
listDouble = listDouble.Where(x => !Double.IsInfinity(x)).ToList();
```

To replace infinite values with `0`:

```
listDouble = listDouble.Select(x => Double.IsInfinity(x) ? 0 : x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `IsNegativeInfinity` and `IsPositiveInfinity` or just the `IsInfinity` method **instead** of comparing to `Double.NegativeInfinity` or `Double.PositiveInfinity`.

```
List<Double> doubles = new List<Double> { Double.NegativeInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity, 1.1, 2.0 };
var newList = doubles.RemoveAll(Double.IsInfinity);
```

Answer (score 1):

I doubt values that are equal to Infinity are also equal to `0`. Try this.

```
listDouble.RemoveAll(item => item.IsPositiveInfinity());
```

Or if you're trying to remove values that are zero and those that are Infinity, then you have to change the `&&` to `||`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is how it looks like for you:

[image]

Just check with `Double.IsInfinity()` like this:

```
doubles.RemoveAll(doub => Double.IsInfinity(doub));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're checking only for negative infinity, you need to add check for positive infinity

```
listDouble.RemoveAll(x => x == double.PositiveInfinity || x == double.NegativeInfinity);
```

or just:

```
listDouble.RemoveAll(x => double.IsInfinity(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to address `double.PositiveInfinity` and `double.NegativeInfinity` constants instead:

```
list.RemoveAll(i => i == double.PositiveInfinity || i == double.NegativeInfinity);
```